# ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building on a MacBook Pro running Catalina 10.15.2.

I'm following the OSX build instructions here:
https://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/macOS/Homebrew/Source

I am at step 2.5.2 (Building the Catkin Workspace).

I provide the command:
`./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=$HOME/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib`

17 packages (of 54) install just fine, then I get the following error when building `rosboost_cfg`:

```
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[$HOME]/melodic_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosboost_cfg/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from catkin.environment_cache import generate_environment_script
ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache
CMake Error at [$HOME]/melodic_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python2
  "[$HOME]melodic_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosboost_cfg/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  [$HOME]/melodic_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:208 (safe_execute_process)
  [$HOME]/melodic_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

I have reviewed @mikepurvis work from a few years ago for `catkin_tools` (https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/378) and the associated PR (https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/pull/391).

I'm having the problem with `catkin_make_isolated`, however, and am unsure how I could apply the changes from `catkin_tools`.

I think I'm having the same mutex problems as those previously reported:

If I run `catkin_make_isolated` with `--only-pkg-with-deps=rosboost_cfg`, it builds `catkin` and `rosboost_cfg` without any problems.

I then attempt to run `catkin_make_isolated` with `--ignore-pkg=rosboost_cfg` and it eventually chokes with `ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache` on `rosbuild`.

I attempt the same process on `rosbuild` (i.e., `--only-pkg-with-deps=rosbuild`), but there are enough dependencies there that I eventually get `ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache` while processing one of the dependencies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342662/importerror:-no-module-named-catkin.environment_cache/) by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-27**:
What do the following commands output: `python --version` and `python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__version__)"`?

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-01-27**:
`python --version` is Python 3.7.5.
`python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__version__)"` is 0.4.16.

My Python symlink should be to 2.7.  I changed it (now reporting Python 2.7.16).  I reran the `rosdep` commands and then rebuild the workspace.  It worked.

I still had to `brew install lz4`.

I can convert this into an answer, unless you want to flesh it out with some detail about why I got the error consistently for certain packages with Python 3, and why it was partially fixed by only building the offending package and its dependencies.  It might not help anyone, but I am curious...

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Either the Python package `catkin_pkg` is not new enough or can't be found.

In this case you are using Python 3 but only have the package installed for Python 2. Using Python 2 made it work.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0